# Selecting hierarchy in wizard

Tags: hierarchy, wizard

I have a wizard and in one of the steps, when the user selects the item, he'll get the list of subitems based on item selected. Once he selects the subitem he can preview the details of the subitem  to check if his selection is correct.

Both these lists can be huge and only one item can be selected at a time.

I am attaching the mockup. Please suggest if this mock up looks good or are there any better designs\examples available for reference.
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a combobox for those lists? It's hard to understand from the mockup.

Using a combobox with free typing/suggestion option will be a better idea for both of the selectors (if you have a lot of options). The combobox will open on focus.

This will allow for a less cluttered and overwhelming layout and will also give you more space for designing better error indications and/or tips for the user.

Here's a quick example:

Edit: By 'Item 1' I meant the **Main Item**, by 'Item 2' - **Sub Item**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I added list box so that if there are fewer items then the user can see all the items at one glance and selects them and this also reduces user clicks. Otherwise user have to perform two clicks to select item 1 and then two clicks to select item 2. After seeing details if he doesn't like the option then again have to go through the entire process. Just wondering if using millers column is a better approach

Comment: While you are correct, I wouldn't suggest counting clicks as a measure of usability performance. As I said, the problem with the Miller columns for me is that it forces a cluttered  layout which will have a greater effect on the usability performance. I guess it also depends on the context. Is it a win/osx app? a website?- why would the user won't like his first selection? Maybe this is a more important issue to address?

Comment: This is windows app. Basically the second drop down will have list of systems and he needs to check which softwares are installed to choose the best fit. Software details will appear under detail tab. So there is high possibility that he iterates through the list before deciding on one of it.

Comment: Understood.
Take into consideration though that win users are not used to the Miller system as osx users.
Best of luck!

Comment: The mockup provided by ekivshany was liked by the experts here, so marking it as answer.